# (C++) Reading a CSV text file as a vector of integers

Tags: c++, csv, integer, fstream

I'm a beginner programmer working through the 2019 Advent of Code challenges in C++.

The last piece of the puzzle I'm putting together is actually getting the program to read the input.txt file, which is essentially a long string of values in the form of '10,20,40,23" etc. on a single line.

In the previous puzzle I used the lines

```
int inputvalue;
std::ifstream file("input.txt");

while(file >> inputvalue){
    //
}
```

to grab lines from the file, but it was formatted as a text file in sequential lines with no comma separation.

ie:

```
10
20
40
23
```

What can I do to read through the file using the comma delineation, and specifically how can I get those values to be read as integers, instead of as strings or chars, and store them into a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would be strange to write a routine to read just one line from a comma separated file, instead of writing a general routine to read all lines (and just take the first one if you only wanted one) -- you can take out the parts for reading multiple lines into a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and just read one line into a `std::vector<int>` -- though it only saves a handful of lines of code.

The general approach would be to read the entire line of text with `getline(file, line)` and then create a `std::stringstream (line)` from which you could then use `>>` to read each integer followed by a `getline (file, tmpstr, ',')` to read the delimiter.

You can take a second argument in addition to the file to read, so you can pass the delimiter as the first character of the second argument -- that way there is no reason to re-compile your code to handle delimiters of `';'` or `','` or any other single character.

You can put a short bit of code together to do that which could look like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    if (argc < 2) { /* validate at least 1 argument given */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient number of arguments.\n"
                    "usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    std::vector<int> v {};              /* vector<int> */
    std::string line {};                /* string to hold each line */
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);          /* open file-stream with 1st argument */
    const char delim = argc > 2 ? *argv[2] : ',';   /* delim is 1st char in  */
                                                    /* 2nd arg (default ',') */
    
    if (!f.good()) {    /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "errro: file open failed '" << argv[1] << "'.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (getline (f, line)) {            /* read line of input into line */
        int itmp;                       /* temporary integer to fill */
        std::stringstream ss (line);    /* create stringstream from line */
        
        while (ss >> itmp) {            /* read integer value from ss */
            std::string stmp {};        /* temporary string to hold delim */
            v.push_back(itmp);          /* add to vector */
            getline (ss, stmp, delim);  /* read delimiter */
        }
    }
    
    for (auto col : v)                  /* loop over each integer */
        std::cout << "  " << col;       /* output col value */
    std::cout << '\n';                  /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

(**note:** there are relatively few changes needed to read all lines into a vector of vectors, the more notable is simply replacing the `if(getline...)` with `while(getline..)` and then filling a temporary vector which, if non-empty, is then pushed back into your collection of vectors)

**Example Input File**

With a set of comma separated integers in the file named `dat/int-1-10-1-line.txt`, e.g.

```
$ cat dat/int-1-10-1-line.txt
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

**Example Use/Output**

Your use an results would be:

```
$ ./bin/read_csv_int-1-line dat/int-1-10-1-line.txt
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

Of course you can change the output format to whatever you need. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It is initializing the stringstream `ss` to contain the contents of `line` `:)` A stringstream is basically an I/O buffer where you can store text from many sources and then use the normal iostream function overloads like `>>` to extract and convert data to the type you need. (you can add to the stringstream in the same way) See [std::basic_stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) for the details.

Comment: Hey, thank you! That was really helpful! I've never encounted a "stringstream" before, and so I'll be doing some digging into it on my own! Two hopefully short and simple questions: 1) Am I correct in reading this bit of code: "std::stringstream ss (line)" as essentially initializing a stringstream named "ss" by casting the string named "line"? 2) Additionally, what is the purpose of the string named "stmp"? In testing my code, nothing gets assigned to it at any point. It's only used as an arg in "getline". As far as I can tell it's just there to meet the overload's requirements?

Comment: `stmp` is just a temporary string to read up to the delimiter into from the stringstream. (it has to have some place to go). So you just declare a temporary string and extract up to the delimiter into that temp string (it may be empty and you don't do anything with it) so your next use of `>>` will extract the integer after the delimiter. It's basically just scratch storage to get rid of the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You have options.  In my opinion, the most straight-forward is to just read a string and then convert to integer.  You can use the additional "delimiter" parameter of `std::getline` to stop when it encounters a comma:

```
std::string value;
while (std::getline(file, value, ',')) {
    int ival = std::stoi(value);
    std::cout << ival << std::endl;
}
```

A common alternative is to read a single character, expecting it to be a comma:

```
int ival;
while (file >> ival) {
    std::cout << ival << std::endl;

    // Skip comma (we hope)
    char we_sure_hope_this_is_a_comma;
    file >> we_sure_hope_this_is_a_comma;
}
```

If it's possible for whitespace to also be present, you may want a less "hopeful" technique to skip the comma:

```
    // Skip characters up to (and including) next comma
    for (char c; file >> c && c != ',';);
```

Or simply:

```
    // Skip characters up to (and including) next comma
    while (file && file.get() != ',');
```

Or indeed, if you expect *only* whitespace *or* a comma, you could do something like:

```
    // Skip comma and any leading whitespace
    (file >> std::ws).get();
```

Of course, all the above are more-or-less clunky ways of doing this:

```
    // Skip characters up to (and including) next comma on next read
    file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',');
```

All these approaches assume input is a single line.  If you expect multiple lines of input with comma-separated values, you'll also need to handle end-of-line occurring *without* encountering a comma.  Otherwise, you might miss the first input on the next line.  Except for the "hopeful" approach, which will work but only on a technicality.

For robustness, I generally advise you to read line-based input as a whole string with `std::getline`, and then use `std::istringstream` to read individual values out of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another compact solution using iterators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>


template <char D>
struct WordDelimiter : public std::string
{};

template <char D>
std::istream &
operator>>(std::istream & is, WordDelimiter<D> & output)
{
  // Output gets every comma-separated token
  std::getline(is, output, D);
  return is;
}

int main() {
  // Open a test file with comma-separated tokens
  std::ifstream f{"test.txt"};
  
  // every token is appended in the vector
  std::vector<std::string> vec{ std::istream_iterator<WordDelimiter<','>>{ f },
                                std::istream_iterator<WordDelimiter<','>>{} };

  // Transform str vector to int vector
  // WARNING: no error checking made here
  std::vector<int> vecint;
  std::transform(std::begin(vec),std::end(vec),std::back_inserter(vecint),[](const auto& s) { return std::stoi(s); });

  for (auto val : vecint) {
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```